# AttributeError: module 'request' has no attribute 'urlopen'

Tags: python, html, url, compiler-errors, urllib

I Keep getting this error,  I am so confused

[image]

Comment: replace `import urllib as request` with `import urllib`. Also, post code as code here instead  of posting link to images

Answer (score 0):

What you are probably trying to do is to import the `request` module from the `urllib` package, so you can use the `urlopen` function defined in the `request` module.

```py
import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlopen('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Additional information:

> The legacy urllib.urlopen function from Python 2.6 and earlier has been discontinued; urllib.request.urlopen() corresponds to the old urllib2.urlopen. Proxy handling, which was done by passing a dictionary parameter to urllib.urlopen, can be obtained by using ProxyHandler objects. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html)